# Conditional body class for home page

Tags: wordpress, class, conditional-statements, document-body

I am trying to add a conditional body class that will only be on the home page.  I found a conditional filter for woocommerce shop page, but when I change is_shop to is_home, it does not work. Here is what I am trying to modify for "home" page.

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {

if ( is_home() ) {

    $classes[] = 'class-name';
    $classes[] = 'class-name-two';

}

return $classes;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional tag you were using, `is_home()`, rather misleadingly only applies to the 'blog homepage'.

The 'blog homepage' isn't necessarily your site's homepage. It's dependent upon the setting used for "Front page displays" under Settings -> Reading. If your homepage is set to a static page then `is_home()` will return true on the "Posts" page.

The conditional you're looking for is `is_front_page()`. This function is going to return true when on the homepage, regardless of whether it's a blog index or a static.

Docs:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/

Answer (score 0):

I added "home" after is_page and it's working now.

```
add_filter( 'body_class','my_body_classes' );
function my_body_classes( $classes ) {

if ( is_page('home') ) {

    $classes[] = 'home-page';
    $classes[] = 'class-name-two';

}

return $classes;

}
```